# Predictions Data don't export into BigQuery

Tags: firebase, firebase-predictions

I have problems with exporting predictions data into bigquery
I followed instructions in documentations, but the result is broken. I see the datasets firebase_predictions and firebase_predictions_v2 in bigquery console, but they are empty . There is no any tables there . Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry. The data now appears. It seems there is a huge (more than 1 day) delay before the data exports into bigquery after linking.